# How to Fetch Rows from Database as a Set in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Instead of using `List` as one is default value when Hibernate queries (`SELECT`) rows, I want to use `Set`. How does fetch rows as a Set in Hibernate? What will happen when in case rows contain duplicate entries except its primary key?

Here, give an instance querying rows if using List. I want to switch `List` to `Set`.

```
List<Student> students = [objectSessionFactory].getCurrentSession
.createQuery("from Student")
.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `Set` in your POJO, Hibernate will map it to the database table using a `PersistentSet`. Regarding dublicated entries: Mak sure you properly implement hashcode and equals of your object...

Comment: thanks for the response. I've just got updated my question. I am sorry, previous sentences doesn't point to my problem. English is not my native language. Would you reply my recent updated question?